# strange behaviour of char

Tags: c, char, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

If `char a = -128;` it is represented in binary as `10000000`.

but when I shift this binary equivalent to the left side by by one bit it gives me `-256`  for which my brain doesn't make any sense.

Can anyone explain it to me how this strange behaviour comes?

```
int main(){
char  a=-128;
printf("%d",a<<1);
return 0;   
 }
```

Comment: integer promotion. Read it first. Almost all C-based languages use it and there are a lot of questions about it here

Answer (score 4):

As per the rule<sup>#</sup> of shifting operator,

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands.  [...]

So, while using `a<<1` as the argument for `printf()`, `a` being of type `char` and `1` being the type of `int` (literal), `a` value is promoted to type `int` and then, the shifting will be performed, then the result will be printed out *as* an `int` value.

---

[#] - `C11`, chapter §6.5.7, *Bitwise shift operators*

Answer (score 4):

`-128` on an `int`  variable is `0xffffff80`.

The shifting left result is `0xffffff00` that is `-256`.

You can test it with this code:

```
int main(void) 
{
    int n = -128;

    printf("Decimal value = %d\n", n);
    printf("Hex value = %x\n", n);

    n<<=1;

    printf("Decimal value = %d\n", n);
    printf("Hex Value = %x\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**
In your code `printf` is promoting your `char` variable to `int` before shifting it.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I guessed it was wrong the title, because of the result of shifting a char will be 0 instead of -256.

Comment: The `char` is promoted to `int` before shifting.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, I wrote it,. There wasn't the code in the first version of question.